# ClickListener on multiple view item type in RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I have a RecyclerView which is populated with 2 kinds of list item, **Books** and **Recipe**.
For this to work I have created an abstract view holder and 2 view holders for books and recipes each and have binded them together. Its working
perfectly. What I am stuck with is I want to set a click listener on the recycler view items and get some data according to that in another view.
Assume that my recycler view has 5 items (3 books and 2 recipes) I have successfully implemented the click listener for the book items and the result is showing as expected.
However, for recipes was getting an error saying `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 1` in Line ABC (marked in my code inside the SearchResultActivity class) unless i get the size of the previews viewholder and minus from the position to reset the position to 0. 
However i dont think this is the proper way to do it as this will increase redundant code if i have say 5 different view holders.

**Question:
How do I set the listener correctly here?**

SearhResultActivity (Shows the recycler view with data)

```
public class SearchResultActivity extends HomeActivity {

private static final String TAG = "SearchResultActivity";

private static final String TAG = "SearchResultActivity";
protected FrameLayout frames;
@BindView(R.id.search_result_recycler)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private SearchRecyclerAdapter searchRecyclerAdapter;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
  ButterKnife.bind(this);

  frames = findViewById(R.id.search_bar_holder);
  mFragmentManager = (this).getSupportFragmentManager();
  mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.search_bar_holder, new SearchTabFragment()).commit();

  recyclerFunctions();

}

public void recyclerFunctions() {
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // use a linear layout manager
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ArrayList<Book> getBookArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    getBookArrayList = (ArrayList<Book>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("bookList");

    ArrayList<Recipe> getRecipeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    getRecipeArrayList = (ArrayList<Recipe>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("recipeList");

    searchRecyclerAdapter = new SearchRecyclerAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(searchRecyclerAdapter);
    //searchRecyclerAdapter.add(foodData);
    searchRecyclerAdapter.add(getBookArrayList);
    searchRecyclerAdapter.add(getRecipeArrayList);


    final ArrayList<Book> finalGetBookArrayList = getBookArrayList;
    final ArrayList<Recipe> finalGetRecipeArrayList = getRecipeArrayList;


    searchRecyclerAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new SearchRecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int i) {

            int itemType = searchRecyclerAdapter.getItemViewType(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: " + searchRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount()+""+searchRecyclerAdapter.getItemId(i));



            if (itemType == TYPE_BOOK){
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchResultActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("bookData", finalGetBookArrayList.get(i));
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);


            } else if (itemType == TYPE_RECIPE){

                int size = finalGetBookArrayList.size();
                /*LINE ABC*/
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchResultActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("recipeData", finalGetRecipeArrayList.get(i - size));
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

SearchRecyclerAdapter (This adapter holders the codes for declaration and connecting all the viewHolders to the abstract viewHolder with connects to the recycler view and OnItemClickListener interface)

```
package com.example.naisse.AdapterAndClass;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.naisse.Api.Model.Search.Food;
import com.example.naisse.Api.Model.Search.Quran;
import com.example.naisse.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class SearchRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchRecyclerAdapter.AbstractViewHolder>{

private static final String TAG = "SearchRecyclerAdapter";

public static final int TYPE_FOOD = 0;
public static final int TYPE_BOOK = 1;

private Context context;
private List<Object> data;

private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int i);
}

/*I belive im missing something here*/
public SearchRecyclerAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public void add(ArrayList newData){
    if(data == null){
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    data.addAll(newData);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public AbstractViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    switch (i){
        case TYPE_BOOK:{
            /*search_result_fragment is the xml layout for food adapter*/
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewholder_book, viewGroup, false);
            return new BookViewAdapter(view, mListener);
        }
        case TYPE_RECIPE:{
            /*search_result_fragment is the xml layout for book adapter*/
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewholder_recipe, viewGroup, false);
            return new RecipeViewAdapter(view, mListener);
        }

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type");

    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AbstractViewHolder abstractViewHolder, int i) {
  Object object = data.get(i);

  if (abstractViewHolder instanceof BookViewAdapter) {
      abstractViewHolder.bind(object);
  } else if (abstractViewHolder instanceof RecipeViewAdapter) {
      abstractViewHolder.bind(object);
  } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid position");
  }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int i){
    Object object = data.get(i);

    if (object instanceof Book){
        return TYPE_BOOK;
    }else if (object instanceof Recipe){
        return TYPE_RECIPE;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid position");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data == null ? 0 : data.size();
}

public abstract class AbstractViewHolder<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public AbstractViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public abstract void bind(T type);
}


public class BookViewAdapter extends AbstractViewHolder<Book> {
    @BindView(R.id.result_book_title)
    TextView bookTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.result_book_content)
    TextView content;

    private BookViewAdapter(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener){
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(position);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(Book type) {
        bookTitle.setText("Book");
        content.setText("title");
    }

}

public class RecipeViewAdapter extends AbstractViewHolder<Recipe> {
    @BindView(R.id.result_recipe_title)
    TextView recipesTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.result_recipe_content)
    TextView content;

    private RecipeViewAdapter(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener){
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(position);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(Recipe type) {
        recipesTitle.setText("title");
        content.setText("Text");
    }

}

}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Can't see where your new the SearchRecyclerAdapter object code,do it before recyclerView.setAdapter(searchRecyclerAdapter) ,and you should do ButterKnife.bind(this) in SearchResultActivity's onCreate after setContentView(...)

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand why calling "bundle.putSerializable" inside a loop. But there's a way to solve the problem which is setting the click listener inside bind() function of two RecipeViewAdapter like this:

```
@Override
public void bind(Recipe type) {
    recipesTitle.setText("title");
    content.setText("Text");
    // setOnClickListener here, and pass the "type" object for further use.
    // this onClickListener handles Recipe item only. 
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void bind(Book type) {
    bookTitle.setText("Book");
    content.setText("title");
    // setOnClickListener here, and pass the "type" object for further use.
    // this onClickListener handles Book item only. 
}
```

In this way, you need not worry about index of the array.

Comment: I did not quite get what you are trying to mean. Can i get an example. Also i have updated my question (i have solved the issue) but i want a more efficient way of doing it.